# Datatable fixed header with buttons

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

- I have [Color Admin Template](http://seantheme.com/color-admin-v2.0/admin/html/index.html)
- I m using fixed header table to display data : [Fixed Header Table](http://seantheme.com/color-admin-v2.0/admin/html/table_manage_fixed_header.html)
- I wanna use button(print,excel,csv,etc...) in fixed header table mentioned in following table [Button Table](http://seantheme.com/color-admin-v2.0/admin/html/table_manage_buttons.html)
- What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

I added a second `tr` tag inside my `thead` tag with `id="th-buttons"`

```
<thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #99b3ff">
        <th id="th-buttons" class="dt-buttons table-header-buttons" colspan="6" rowspan="1"></th>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
```

Then in my JS I initiated the [buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) using the [direct insertion](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/#Direct-insertion) with a new constructor.

You can see the Demo here: http://codepen.io/sshel/pen/xqmQqM

Comment: FixedHeader copies/recalculates the columns widths from the first row so the widths of the columns get messed up once you scroll. A quick fix is to add one more dummy row with empty cells above the button row with the same number of columns as your table.